# Locking a txt file with python

Tags: python, windows, io, locking

Is there any way to lock a text file (*both Read & Write*) with python script? Or is there any module or built in function for that? While running the script, i want the users not to be able to open the text file and change stuffs inside.FYI,I am using windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [lockfile](http://pythonhosted.org/lockfile/) should meet your needs